# problem with displaying Excel files

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

[image]I am designing an Intranet workspace for my company.

The requirements are to display `multiple Excel files`(max 5) in a single page created. The design is displayed in my computer but when looking into others computer, I am getting the following error message,

> "an error occurred during the execution of the requested action. try
>   again"

Sometimes the webpage loses its connection and refreshing 3 to 4 times, I am getting back.

Sorry its In French but when you translate you will get the above error message

Comment: Are you looking for an option how to display the Excel files? If not, please explain how you are currently doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If You are using SharePoint 2013: Use the "Search Results Web Part". In the configuration You can point it to the Library (or libraries) You want to fetch the documents from and configure it to show only 5 elements.

Comment: I am using SharePoint 2010. the excel documents are already fetched and displayed on the pages created and when I see I don't get that error message but for some people whom I give the rights to view these excel documents has been displayed with the above error message.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please tell us which permissions you gave to users, and which kind of account you use for?
I suppose that is a problem of permission if you can access to your page but not for the others.
http://blogs.technet.com/b/excel_services__powerpivot_for_sharepoint_support_blog/archive/2013/05/21/excel-services-the-workbook-cannot-be-opened.aspx
Bon Courage.

Comment: Its the Proprietor level of permission ie when I gave the total control access , it is still having the same problem. Also to your note, I don't have the SharePoint administrator rights to make modifications as per the blog link shared above. I am just a designer. Bon Journee

Comment: I suggest you create a page which contains only one Excel Web Part to test if the others can visite the Excel or not.